# Are there experimental signatures unique to Mott insulators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, many-body

Mott insulators are differentiated from band insulators because they are insulators due to their strong electron-electron interactions.

Although Mott insulators are defined using a specific model,  I want to ask the following question:

Is there an experimental way to differentiate between an insulator due to strong Coulomb repulsion and a band insulator that does not rely on any calculations or assumptions about the Hamiltonian?

If we consider other phases such as ferromagnets, ferroelectrics, piezoelectrics, superconductors, etc. each have very specific experimental signatures that do not rely on doping, chemical changes,  calculations, models, fitting, etc. On the other hand, for Mott insulators I don't know of any such unique signatures without referring to external information.

Comment: Well the gap has to be zero to all orders in perturbation theory, so you end up with a really small gap of order $e^{-1/g}$, where $g$ is the coupling constant. This is probably something you could look for. But in general, there's no reason the strong interactions couldn't still lead to a trivial gapped state. This is the case for QCD, for instance. The ultimate Mott insulator perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Since Mott insulators and band insulators are both gapped, incompressible, insulating states, there aren't many signatures that would distinguish between them without some additional knowledge of the system. But here is a brief list of the tests that you might do, and the knowledge that each requires:

- Density measurements. Probably the most important and practical test is just measuring the density of the system. If it is an insulator, but it is at half-filling (i.e., there is exactly one particle per Wigner–Seitz cell), then it cannot be a band insulator. This does not require detailed knowledge of the microscopic Hamiltonian, just the crystal structure and carrier density.
- Excitation measurements. The fundamental excitations in a Mott insulator are particle-hole excitations, while in a band insulator they are band excitations. So, if one knows at least something about the relative hierarchy between the interaction scale and bandgap, by studying the excitations of the system it might also be possible to distinguish between the two states. This, again, requires some microscopic knowledge, but not necessary full information about the Hamiltonian.
- Finally, if it is possible to vary the interaction strength one can observe the metal-Mott insulator phase transition directly. As far as I know, this is the only test that doesn't require any microscopic knowledge. It isn't possible with electrons, but can be done in ultracold gases in optical lattices.

One final comment: in Hubbard's original paper ([paywalled link, sorry](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/276/1365/238)), he develops an approximate picture for the Hubbard model under strong interactions as having two remormalized bands separated by the interaction energy. So, within this approximate picture, a Mott insulator is in a sense a type of band insulator, with a bandgap that is created by the interactions.

There are also various papers that tackle this question directly for a particular model ([2](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0510150v2)).

Comment: Great! Regarding your first point, are there any other examples of insulating systems with one particle per cell? Just would like to know if this is a unique test for Mott insulators. Could you also elaborate some more on point #2? The elementary excitations of all insulators are particle-hole pairs across the gap, right? Some more details on this section would be great.

Comment: To your first question: In principle, an Anderson insulator (that is, something that is insulating due to disorder) can have one particle per cell (or any other filling). So it is not completely unique. In a disorder-free system, I cannot think offhand of any other possibility. I will try to add a bit more about the second point later.

Comment: I have added some elaboration.

Comment: Topological band insulators are always realized at integer filling too.

Comment: I still don't understand the distinction you are making between particle-hole excitations and "band" excitations. If I look at something like the reflectivity or optical conductivity (frequency dependent current response) both of these excitations would be the same. Perhaps I'm missing something, but I'm not seeing how you would distinguish these even in principle.

Comment: Creating a particle-hole excitation means, roughly, going from two sites that have one atom each to one doubly-occupied site and one unoccupied site. A band excitation, by contrast, need not change the site occupation. So they are not identical. Whether that difference shows up in a particular macroscopic response is another question, of course.

Comment: @Rococo, I see what you're saying: both of those are particle hole excitations, but for the Mott insulator it is a highly local excitation, whereas a band insulator has delocalized excitations with well defined crystal momentum.

Comment: @Rococo, with the localized nature in mind, what does the hierarchy of energy scales have to do with it?

Comment: @user157879 They are two separate issues. But, if for example you see a gapped insulator with a gap that is much smaller than the known bandgap, one might suspect it is a Mott insulator.

Comment: See for example https://arxiv.org/abs/0804.4009, where a Mott insulator of ultracold atoms is probed by creating particle-hole excitations and measuring the resulting change in double occupancy. Of course, in that particular case they do know the microscopic Hamiltonian, which makes it all less ambiguous.

Comment: " both of those are particle hole excitations, but for the Mott insulator it is a highly local excitation, whereas a band insulator has delocalized excitations with well defined crystal momentum." - actually, this isn't quite right. A Mott insulator excitation can be delocalized with a definite quasimomentum, since the double occupancies can be thought of as forming their own (so-called Hubbard) band. However, what is definitely true is that a Mott insulator excitation represents a change in the relative probability of doubly vs singly occupied lattice sites, while a band excitation does not.

Comment: @Rococo I see, but the fraction of singly vs doubly occupied sites is not something you can measure in experiment is it? Or is there a method to measure that?

Comment: (1/2) @KFGauss This can be done directly in ultracold atomic realizations of a Mott insulator, as shown in the paper I linked to above. In a conventional solid it is not so straightforward. However, it appears that ultrafast techniques are nowadays getting close to this, by making it possible to excite a Mott insulator, watch it relax, and learn about the nature of the excitation from this relaxation. An example of such a study is here: https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.120.166401. In this study the authors are trying to settle a disagreement

Comment: (2/2) about whether a gap in a material is a Mott gap or due to some other mechanism. They investigate this by creating excitations, and then studying the decay. Because the decay happens on a fast timescale comparable to the tunneling, they conclude (with some theoretical modeling) that the excitations are doublons and the gap is therefore a Mott gap. As far as I know this is the closest thing to this ideal measurement that is possible with today’s technology, but since I am not very familiar with the field of ultrafast techniques I’ll refrain from commenting more.

Comment: @Rococo hmm that paper does not seem to be too convincing, as it still heavily relies on a computation because the experiment is still ambiguous. I guess distinguishing between Mott and band insulator excitations is still an open question in solids.

Comment: Personally, I would not characterize it this way- there are materials that we know with a high confidence to be Mott insulators. But the way we have determined this is more by a preponderance of evidence (starting with knowledge of the electron density and measurements of insulating behavior), rather than the single experimental signature that you would like.